# Quasi-experimental design : time series analysis

Tags: time-series

I am busy designing  a medical research for my masters(epidemiology)on time series analysis, comparing the trends of Pulmonary TB bacteriologically confirmed cases before and after the introduction a diagnosis tool(GeneXpert) with regards to evaluate the new diagnostic tool.
the following is my concern:
- I have less than 50 time points, a friend of mine told i could not use an ARIMA model, but the segmented regression, what can you advise on this statistical issue?

Comment: Having 50 data points is good enough for ARIMA. Do you have a control group?

Comment: unfortunately there is no control group , is sigle time series design, we one group, we are comparing the trend before and after the intervention , if the new the diagnosis tool has increased the proportion of TB cases compared to the time before the intervention ,I  have 48 time points(data  collected from 2010 to 2013, routine data) and more than 250 observations per time point.

Comment: So you actually have more than $48 \times 250$ observations. Which is rather a lot...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a [regression discontinuity design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_discontinuity_design).  In that case, 'control' is before, 'treatment' is after, and two regression models (or a single segmented one) will target the treatment effect at the point of introduction.

You'll want some other quanties for the same time period to do placebo tests.

Since you're getting, at best, a treatment effect at the point of introduction, then 50 data points might well be fine, depending of course on what confounder dynamics are in the background.

Comment: i am having 48 data point from janauary 2010 to 2013, on top of that tere is no control , i have one group on which  i am assessing the intervention effect  with regards to potential confounders

Comment: Have you read the link?  Did it make sense for your problem?